# Como pegar imagem do computador do usuário?

Tags: html, imagem, div

Estou começando a construir um formulário em HTML (bootstrap), e quero adicionar uma div com um botão "adicionar imagem" que seja possível buscar a imagem dentro do computador, e assim que for adicionada a foto, que o usuário consiga digitar uma  legenda abaixo da visualização da mesma.
E ter outro botão para adicionar novas imagens e repetir todo o processo. (js)

Answer (score 1):

Para pegar a imagem do dispositivo do usuário basta utilizar a tag `input` do tipo `file`.
Para mais informações, consulte:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

```html
<input name="myFile" type="file">
```